# Include content of a html file in another html file in CefSharp without a browser

Tags: javascript, html, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp to convert an old WinForms Application into a HTML5 Application.
In my Winforms Application i have several Forms for different Views and Windows.
I wanted to create the same thing with HTML pages.
But when like:

```
 $("#view").load("anotherForm.html", function () {
      alert("Load was performed.");
  });
```

I get the following error: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

It seems like that I need a local web server. Is there a way to bypass this?
I would accept any solution with libraries but without any extra software. I also don't want to use any CefSharp functions because I want to port it someday to be a real web application.

It would be enough to be able to load "html like" code (like divs) into a fixed "MainFrame.html".

I don't see a alternative to hardcode the different "html pages" into my javascript.

Comment: What `scheme` are you using?

Comment: What do you mean with scheme?

Comment: Are you using `http`, `https`, `file` or a `custom` scheme? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Definition for more details on what a `scheme` is.

Comment: Under the hood I use file I think (CefSharp does use it to open the file locally with Chromium). Because of the file scheme i have the described problems.

Comment: You can use a custom scheme handler and use the `http` or `https` protocol see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#scheme-handler